# How to calculate balance in sql?

Tags: c#, sql

I have following table , but I don't know how to calculate balance and status column like below based on debit and credit columns ?

```
| ID |    AR_DATE |ACC_CODE  | ACC_NAME | DETAILS | DEBIT | CREDIT | BALANCE ?| STATUS?|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 2013-04-10 |      101 |      A/R |    Kofi |   500 |      0 |     500  | Debit  |
|  2 | 2013-04-10 |      101 |      A/R |     AMA |     0 |    250 |     250  | Debit  |
|  3 | 2013-04-11 |      101 |      A/R |    Boss |     0 |     50 |     200  | Debit  |
|  4 | 2013-04-12 |      101 |      A/R |    Jhon |     0 |    300 |     100  | Credit |
```

Comment: Should the last balance be -100 ?

Comment: This is, to put it mildly, not a good table design to work with. For example you never really know if `Balance` is really "positive" or "negative" by itself. You always have to look at the `Status`. If instead of `Debit/Credit` fields you'd just have one `Changes` field with `500, -250, -50, -300` you could easily calculate whatever you need. Now, I know that financial software has some ridiculous requirements, but isn't at least the data storage irelevant when you can *display* the data like the table you've shown?

Comment: @Corak this is a running total calculation based on the balance of the previous record. The status can be disregarded in this context since (Debit - Credit) will get you the actual value of the transaction. It could be due to performance requirements that you want to keep the Balance there, at least as a stored computed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT ID,
       AR_DATE,
       ACC_CODE,
       ACC_NAME,
       DETAILS,
       DEBIT,
       CREDIT,
       SUM(DEBIT - CREDIT) OVER(ORDER BY AR_DATE ASC) AS BALANCE,
       CASE WHEN CREDIT > 0 THEN 'Credit' ELSE 'Debit' END AS STATUS,
FROM [WhateverTable]
```

When you don't have 2012 you need to construct it a bit more complex: ([source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server))

```
SELECT ID,
       AR_DATE,
       ACC_CODE,
       ACC_NAME,
       DETAILS,
       DEBIT,
       CREDIT,
       (SELECT SUM(b.DEBIT - b.CREDIT) 
        FROM [WhateverTable] b
        WHERE b.AR_DATE <= a.AR_DATE) AS BALANCE,
       CASE WHEN CREDIT > 0 THEN 'Credit' ELSE 'Debit' END AS STATUS,
FROM [WhateverTable] a
```

Comment: The OVER clause related to the SUM

Answer (score -1):

```
select case when Debit>0 then balance=balance+debit else
balance=balance-credit end as balance,case when Balance  > Credit then
'Debit' else 'Credit'  end as Status from  tableName
```

Try above query.

Comment: `case when Debit > Credit then 'Debit' else 'Credit' end as Status` wouldn't that cause the output `Status` to be `Debit, Credit, Credit, Credit` instead of the shown `Debit, Debit, Debit, Credit`?

Comment: @Corak Yeah, you are right, it will, just now observed that issue. But not able to understand logic behind it.

Comment: As far as i understand it: first there is `Debit = 500` resulting in a `Balance = 500`. Next there is a `Credit = 250` resulting in a `Balance = (500 - 250) = 250` then `Credit = 50` => `Balance = (250 - 50) = 200` then `Credit = 300` => `Balance = (200 - 300) = -100`. That's why @Bas Brekelmans asked.

Comment: @Corak see my new edited condition. Will it be fine? Its according to my observation

Comment: This does not calculate running totals as required. it is fixed on a single record!